# Pycharm and syntax errors

Tags: pycharm

When I've made a syntax error and debug my program in PyCharm (CE 3.4), the syntax error is thrown as an exception on runtime, with the debugger landing somewhere inside a PyCharm file (pydevd.py).

Is it possible to get PyCharm to stop and highlight the syntax error in my file instead, exactly like when I run the program instead of debugging it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out pycharm inspections. https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/code-inspection.html

This should be setup by default and the should throw a red highlight to the right side of your editor window that will then show you where the error is on mouseover.